# Adding 2 google maps with different coordinates on same page

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, maps, wordpress-theming

I have been working with a wordpress theme that has the support to just add coordinates in a menu and directly display the map on the contact page. Now I have a new business address that needs to be added to the contact map but the theme doesn't support that.

Giving the fact that my experience in php and js is limited I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

My code for the contact page is bellow and all I need is to add a new map with different coords before the contact form.

```
<div id="content">
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();
        $show_map = get_option('theme_gmap_show');
        if($show_map == 'true')
        {
        $map_lati = get_option('theme_gmap_lati');
        $map_longi = get_option('theme_gmap_longi');
        $map_zoom = get_option('theme_gmap_zoom');
    ?>                                                   
    <div class="map-container clearfix">
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>                         
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() 
            {
            var geocoder  = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $map_lati; ?>, <?php echo $map_longi; ?>);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var myOptions = { 
                zoom: <?php echo $map_zoom; ?>,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            geocoder.geocode( { 'location': latlng }, 
              function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       map: map, 
                       position: results[0].geometry.location
                  });                                                                                                
                } 
                else 
                {
                  alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
             });
           }
           initialize();
           </script>        
          </div>                                                                                                                                
    <?php                                                   
    } 
    the_content(); 
            $postal_address = stripslashes(get_option('theme_postal_address'));
    if(!empty($postal_address))
    {
    ?>                                                                                                                                                                  
            <h3 class="smart-head">Adresa de contact</h3>
    <p><address>
   <?php echo $postal_address; ?>
</address></p>
<?php
}
?>
     <div class="contact-orar">
     <h3 class="smart-head">Program de Lucru</h3>
     <p><strong>Luni - Vineri:</strong> 8:00 - 17:00<br />
     <strong>Sambata:</strong> 8:00 - 14:00<br />
     <strong>Duminica:</strong> inchis</p>
     </div>
     <div class="contact-form-container">
```

Thank in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Even without any `PHP` knowledge you should be able to manage adding a map, the code uses the Google Maps API v3. You can easiliy add another map using JavaScript. First of all add another div with ID `map_canvas_2` next you should use the following Javascript code:

```
<script>
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(/*latitude here*/,/*longitude here*/)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas_2'),
        mapOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

This will display a map centered on the coordinates you specify in the `map_canvas_2` div. You can find more information here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

**JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chycx/2/**

Comment: This code isn't working it looks like it won't load the second map from google.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote `map-canvas_2` instead of `map_canvas_2`. I updated the code. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a random key to the end of the call to your query.  This is an example using KML layers, but it is the same concept.

```
$( function() {

   $(".map_canvas").each( function() {

           var theElement = $(this).attr('id');
           var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
           var lon = $(this).attr('lon');
           var kml = $(this).attr('kml');

           var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
           var mapOptions = {
             zoom: 14,
             center: mapCenter,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           }

           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(theElement), mapOptions);
           var geopoints = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://blah.com/temps/kmls/' + kml + '.kml?run=' + (new Date()).getTime() ); //?nocache=0
           geopoints.setMap(map);
   });

})
```

Comment: The reason is Google caches the query from your site to alleviate load on their servers.  The second call is just getting a cached map.